# What do you call the university or school from which people graduated?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The alumni of a school, college, or university are the people who used to be students there.

But what do you call the university or school one person graduated from in one word or one phrase?

Comment: He went to... She read X at ... He was at... She is a X graduate...

Comment: there's really no term, as such, for this.  there is "alma mater" which is basically a comedy term for it.

Comment: @JoeBlow Why is that "a comedy term"?

Comment: Hi Joshua ... I mean one can only make a value judgement.  (As with absolutely any question, whatsoever, about word usage.)  I have never heard it used other than with a smile or an outright joke.  It's an "old-fashioned" term, if you will.

Answer (score 61):

Good old FU.  That's my

> **alma mater**
>
> al·ma ma·ter
> älmə ˈmädər
> noun
>
> the school, college, or university that one once attended.
> the anthem of a school, college, or university.
>
> Source: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=alma+mater&oq=alma+mater&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

It sounds funny because it's a Latin phrase. The words literally mean:

> alma, "nourishing/kind"
>
> mater, "mother"
>
> Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alma_mater)

But few English speakers think about that when referring to a school.  It's the kind of thing only us word nerds care about.

Comment: Must have been so awkward for all the Roman kids who were talking about their alma mater to people who just didn't realise they literally meant their kind mother.

Comment: I'd note that _alma mater_ is rarely used in British English.

Comment: I would say its somewhat rare/fancy (like a lot of latin phrases) in American English too, but most people would know what you mean.

Comment: Few english speakers use more than 1000~1500 words, so I wouldn't care about them. Alma mater has a HUGE advantage that almost all western languages recognize the expression.

Comment: Even though this was the first phrase that came to mind, I don't actually use it. I think more people say "my college".

Comment: @JackAidley: just to put some numbers on that, Google ngrams suggests that *alma mater* has been [about 2 to 3 times more common in American English than British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(alma+mater%2BAlma+Mater)%3Aeng_gb_2012%2C+(alma+mater%2BAlma+Mater)%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3) through most of the 20th century.  I would expect most Brits to be familiar with the phrase, though.

Comment: @PLL - to my British ears 'alma mater' sounds almost absurdly pompous.  For myself, and people I know it's usual to say 'The college/Uni I went to ...', or 'My (old) college/Uni ...'.

Comment: @Dan: yep, as a fellow Brit, I’d generally agree.  Having since lived in the States for a fair few years, I’d think of it as a bit pompous in American English too, though not quite as badly so.

Comment: I'm Australian, and graduated from uni more than 10 years ago, and I have *never* heard this expression.

Comment: I'm a Briton and familiar with this term but would be wary of using it in conversation with other Britons and Australians. It might come across as a bit pompous, but that's what you get when you deliberately look for special words to describe things ;-)

Comment: Alma mater is formal, elitist, and pompous.  And so is bragging about where you went to school.  If you were an FU alumnus you'd know this already.  : )

Comment: ["My alma mater? I'll tell you about my alma mater"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B_an_YupJAI)

Comment: One'd use *alma mater* if they went to a well-known/well-reputed school that shaped them deeply (and was a highlight of their life).

Comment: It's definitely something you'd use of the University of Cambridge, not Cambridge Further Education College. In normal speech, "I went to X" is preferred, but sometimes you need to get high-falutin.

Answer (score 12):

In British English, you'd probably just say that the university in question was *your university* or your *old* university

e.g.

> *[My university](http://www.theguardian.com/education/mortarboard/2016/jan/07/seven-university-costs-you-probably-havent-budgeted-for) was very nice*
>
> *[My old university](https://www.timeshighereducation.com/news/aung-san-suu-kyi-inspires-university-oxford-help-myanmar) was Oxford Brookes.*

etc.

Comment: If your university was Oxford or Cambridge, you would probably say "my college" not "my university." I don't know if that usage applies to other collegiate universities in the UK, such as Durham, York, etc. Note, this comment does *not* apply to Oxford Brookes University, which is a separate entity (originally the Oxford School of Art) and not part of the University of Oxford.

Comment: In the US you'd be more likely to say "my college", even if it was a university. I went to Iowa State University, which I refer to as "my college".

Comment: Oxford Brookes? A university? Pah. (:P)

Comment: @alephzero: yes and no.  You might well talk about “my college”, but that would mean the specific college you went to — Trinity, St. John’s, or whatever — within the university.  If you were referring to the university in general — Cambridge or Oxford — you’d definitely say still university, not college.  (I presume this distinction is one of the reasons why the US use of “college” to refer colloquially to any university hasn’t caught on much the UK.)

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet That's what happens when you let politicians have control of education policy. Prime minister Blair made the arbitrary decision that 50% of school leavers in the UK should go to university. The most cost-effective way to do this was obvious: just rename a large number of existing further-education establishments as "universities". The only costs involved were painting new signboards outside the buildings, reprinting their paperwork, and updating their websites. Cheap at half the price!

Comment: And there's always the not-at-all-modest "went to the other place myself"

Comment: @alephzero You are confusing a number of very different things. In 1992, Prime Minister John Major granted UK polytechnics autonomous degree-awarding powers, rather than all having to be validated through the CNAA (so they 'became universities', and most renamed). The point was institutional independence to plan and adapt, and that was a Good Thing. One distraction was _minority_ political rhetoric about 'parity of esteem' with existing universities, which was not in fact an issue: everyone who understood education was already aware that the polys were already doing a valuable job very well.

Comment: @alephzero Tony Blair's promise of 50% of school-leavers in higher education was seven years later: populist vote-grabbing aimed at middle- and working-class parents, linking higher education with earnings. No-one explained where huge numbers of graduate-calibre jobs would appear from, or how humans could suddenly perform in this specialised way. Blair may as well have promised half of us places in the Olympics. You also need to know about Thatcher's earlier pledge to _reduce_ access to higher education (which she attempted), and later bizarre reinterpreting of HE funding by Cameron and Clegg.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with **former** school/college/university:

> My **former** university, where I spent 6 amazing years, is XYZ University.

Comment: As a native American English speaker, from that phrasing I would infer that you didn't graduate, or that you actually graduated from a different school. (I.e., the university from which I graduated forever remains "my school", not "my former school".)

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to say that people will often ask someone "where did you get your *education*?" or "where did you *attend* school" so I'd just like to add that it is possible to say "I got my primary *education* at..." or say  "I *attended* college/university at... ". In sum, I think *primary education* or *basic* *education* could be used to state one's education background before university level.

Answer (score 0):

Especially when discussing returning to/visiting such an institution you could use “[my old campus](https://books.google.com/books?id=cBbiAAAAMAAJ&pg=RA3-PA19&dq=%22my+old+campus%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1ytG__bjLAhVFGR4KHcTRDSwQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22my%20old%20campus%22&f=false), although it can be used in other contexts purely as an identifying phrase:
“Things went … a bit bad at my old campus.”
(example of use in “visiting” context from ‘The Michigan Alumnus’ and in “identifying” context from ‘Break Your Heart’ by Rhonda Helms, both via ‘Google Books’)

Although its use in the purely “visiting” context might fall within Merriam-Webster’s first definition below (grounds/buildings), its use to identify and discuss such an institution as “an academic entity” (and not just its grounds and buildings) definitely falls under definition #2, and when used with “my old” could mean “the institution from which I graduated”:

**[campus](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/campus)**
1:  the grounds and buildings of a university, college, or school
2 :  a university, college, or school viewed as an **academic**, social, or spiritual **entity**

Answer (score -1):

These are all very good...

If you are in the US:
"I'm an alumni of Temple University"
"I'm a Penn State Alum"
"I graduated from Harvard"
"I went to college at MIT" ("college" is commonly used even if the school is a "university")
"My alma matter is FSU" (less common admittedly)
"I did my MBA at Wharton"

"alumni" is used more formally or in resume's (we do not use "CV" in the states unless you are an academic)

My friends that are Brits and Indian do say "university" much more as stated in previous posts

hth

Comment: The question is asking for a term for the institution, not its graduates, who anyway should say *I'm an alumnus/alumna*, not *I'm an alumni*, if they were paying attention in class.